# Chef serverspec `describe command` using an or statement

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I would like to use a serverspec check and run it against two acceptable outcomes, so that if either passes then the check passes.  I want my check to pass if the exit status of the command is either 0 or 1.  Here is my check:

```
describe command("rm /var/tmp/*.test") do
  its(:exit_status) { should eq 0 }   
end
```

Right now it can only check if the exit status is 0.  How can I change my check to use either 0 or 1 as an acceptable exit status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a compound matcher.

```
its(:exit_status) { should eq(0).or eq(1) }
```